# Calculus - Solving limits with square roots

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having trouble understanding how to solve this limit by rationalizing. I have the problem correct (I used Wolfram Alpha of course), but I still don't understand how it is completed. I was trying to solve this by multiplying both the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{x^2+11}+6$, but I am stuck. Is that the way to solve this? If so, could you walk me through it so I can solve others?

Problem:
[image]

Comment: Can you factor $x^2-25$?

Comment: I'm really really new to this and haven't taken algebra in a very long time, you are going to have to explain more @GitGud

Comment: Do you know what 'factoring a polynomial' means?

Comment: i have done that before, but I don't understand what you are factoring? the bottom? As you can see i already have the correct answer and unfortunately my book is so cryptic i can't understand it (as most pearson books are), I only need to see how it is done one time and I will understand it, im not asking for bits and pieces. I'm asking for a full explanation.

Comment: I may have misjudged where you are stuck. Factoring $x^2-25$ will be useful, hence my question.Your idea of multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt{x^2+11}+6$ is good though. I'm sure someone will help you momentarily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 5}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+11}-6}{x-5} 
  &= \lim_{x\to 5}\frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+11}-6\right)
    \left(\sqrt{x^2+11}+6\right)}{(x-5)\left(\sqrt{x^2+11}+6\right)} \\[2ex]
  &= \lim_{x\to 5}\frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+11}\right)^2-6^2}
    {(x-5)\left(\sqrt{x^2+11}+6\right)} \\[2ex]
  &= \lim_{x\to 5}\frac{x^2+11-36}{(x-5)\left(\sqrt{x^2+11}+6\right)} \\[2ex]
  &= \lim_{x\to 5}\frac{x^2-25}{(x-5)\left(\sqrt{x^2+11}+6\right)} \\[2ex]
  &= \lim_{x\to 5}\frac{(x-5)(x+5)}{(x-5)\left(\sqrt{x^2+11}+6\right)} \\[2ex]
  &= \lim_{x\to 5}\frac{x+5}{\sqrt{x^2+11}+6} \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{5+5}{\sqrt{5^2+11}+6} \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{10}{12} \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{5}{6}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I see now what @Git Gud was talking about. this is very clear now....i was missing the 5th & 6th step. Thank you. This will help me with further problems like this

Answer (score 1):

A possible step-by-step solution: write $x=y+5$ (so that you are looking for a limit as $y\to 0$), and the denominator is $x-5=y$

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^2+11} &= \sqrt{(y+5)^2+11} = \sqrt{y^2+10y + 36} = \sqrt{36}\sqrt{1+\frac{10}{36}y+\frac{y^2}{36}} \\
&= 6 \sqrt{1+\frac{5}{18}y+\frac{y^2}{36}}
\end{align}
$$

From there,

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^2+11} - 6 &= 6 \left(  \sqrt{1+\frac{5}{18}y+\frac{y^2}{36}} - 1\right)
\end{align}
$$
Now, if you know Taylor series, you can immediately apply the fact that $\sqrt{1+u} = 1+\frac{u}{2} + o(u)$ when $u\to 0$ to get that
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^2+11} - 6 &= 6 \left(  1+\frac{5}{36}y+ o(y) - 1\right)
= 6 \left(  \frac{5}{36}y+ o(y)\right)
= \frac{5}{6}y+ o(y)
\end{align}
$$
and now
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+11} - 6}{y} = \frac{\frac{5}{6}y+ o(y)}{y} = \frac{5}{6} + o(1) \xrightarrow[y\to 0]{} \frac{5}{6}.$$